# Best possible way to handle exception String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, entity-framework-6

My project have an interface through which user can input date range and records in between those dates will be displayed. 
This is my view Model with two strings.

```
public class SearchByDate
    {
        public string Date1 { get; set; }
        public string Date2 { get; set;  }
    }
```

This is the view for this viewModel

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label>From</label>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", required = "required", placeholder = "From" } })
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
       <label>To</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", required = "required", placeholder = "To" } })
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input style="float: right ; background-color:white; color:#e60053 " type="Submit" class="btn" value="Generate Report" onmouseover=" this.style.backgroundColor = '#e60053', this.style.color = 'white' " onmouseout="    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white',   this.style.color = '#e60053'">
    </div>
  }
```

Jquery for those @HTML.EditorFor

```
@section scripts{

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1950:2019",
            //minDate: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
            showOn: "both",
            buttonText: "Select"
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

So i took input and against those two input fields i am running query on my code

```
 var result = (from entity in Dbset.ToList()
                      where DateTime.Parse(entity.Date) >= DateTime.Parse(@from) &&
                      DateTime.Parse(entity.Date) <= DateTime.Parse(to)
                      select entity);
```

It is working perfectly fine but if i give not a valid date for example if i passed "2018" or "12" or anything else which is not a valid date it throws exception on query "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**".
what is the best possible way to handle it ?

Comment: why aren't you defining you dates as DateTime instead of string?  The modelbinder will attempt to make the conversion for you before you get into you query.  you could also and validation on the model so that your from date is always less than your to date.

Comment: There is a couple of reason for doing it , and i am using it in my entire project so i cant change it now .. well i came up with the answer by searching .. it is solved ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<String>{"2018-01-01","2018-13-13","2020-06-06", "2021-06-06"};

        var today = DateTime.Today;

        DateTime parseDate;

        // Determine valid dates
        var validDates = (from stringDate in list
                          where DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, out parseDate) ? parseDate >= today : false
                          select DateTime.Parse(stringDate));

        Console.WriteLine(okDates.Count()); // 2 valid dates

        // Determine invalid dates
        var invalidDates = (from stringDate in list
                            where !DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, out parseDate)
                            select stringDate);

        Console.WriteLine(invalidDates.Count()); // 1 invalid date


    }
}
```